# Как второй раз запустить поток?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Дело в том что поток с первого раза корректно срабатывает и через цикл я останавливаю этот поток. Потом через какое то время обратно запускаю этот же поток но получаю ошибку

> IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.

Может я неправильно останавливаю или просто у меня логика неправильная. Нужна помощь.

```
SlideThread slideThread;
```

и в onCreate() инициализирую..

```
slideThread = new SlideThread();
```

и тут проверка

```
if (video.getCategory().equals("advertising")) {
    if (slideTHread.isAlive){
        slideThread.interrupt();
    }
}
if (video.getCategory().equals("background")) {
    if (!slideThread.isAlive){
        slideThread.start();
    }
}
```

//....

```
public class SlideThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            final List<Banner> bannerList = GlobalData.loadBannerInfo(MainActivity.this);

            for (int i = 0; i < bannerList.size(); i++) {
                final File file = new File(Application.banner_path + bannerList.get(i).getName());

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mBannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mBannerView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                    }
                });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15 * 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void interrupt() {
            super.interrupt();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mBannerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

и еще даже после завершения потока, все равно через 15 секунд задержки само срабатывает.

Дайте подсказку что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 3):

Метод `start()` у объекта `Thread` можно вызвать лишь единожды.

Поэтому либо встраивайте внутрь потока логику запусков-остановок, либо создавайте и запускайте каждый раз новый поток.

Comment: Если каждый раз буду создавать новый поток и запускать, то смогу ли его завершать?

Comment: Не понимаю вопрос. В вашем же коде вы его завершили?

Answer (score 0):

вы можете внутри метода run сделать условие:

```
public class SlideThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            if (do) {
                final List<Banner> bannerList = GlobalData.loadBannerInfo(MainActivity.this);

                for (int i = 0; i < bannerList.size(); i++) {
                    final File file = new File(Application.banner_path + bannerList.get(i).getName());

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mBannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mBannerView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(15 * 1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void interrupt() {
                super.interrupt();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mBannerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

или типо того. И когда нужно чтобы поток работал вы переменной do дадите значение true и наоборот. Вот только я не уверен что правильно понял вашу просьбу, по этому если я сказал чушь, прошу прощения.